# Iterating a correct Sigma sign to odd zeros.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fourier-series

Trying to compute this integral for my $b_n$'s i a Fourier series exercise I came out with this, eventually:
$$b_n=\frac{8}{\pi n^3}$$ for odd integers and
$$b_n=0$$ for even integers [Which is correct].

Now I want to write the series:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin\left ( \frac{n\pi x}{L} \right )$$
where $L=\pi$. So I think that substitute $n\to 2m+1$ would be correct, but actually the correct answer in my book is this:
$$f(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{8}{\pi (2m-1)^3}\sin\left (2m-1 \right )x$$
Could any one explain why the correct iteration is $n\to 2m-1$?

Comment: If you're going through the odd integers with $2m+1$, you'd need to start with $m=0$; the book's just done $2m-1$ but from $m=1$. It's the same series but with different ways of writing the initial $m$ values. So you are both correct.

Comment: @Eul Can: Thanks a lot!